# Commonize mssql connection

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, express

I'm using mssql on node.js.

I want to Commonize mssql connection.

I would like to summarize the connections generated each time with multiple modules into one file

Could you tell me a good way?

Example

[table1.js]

```
var mssql = require('mssql');
var config = {
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  server: 'server', 
  database: 'db',
  stream: true, 
  options: {
    encrypt: true 
  }
}

mssql.connect(config, function(err) {
    var request = new mssql.Request(); 
    request.query('select * from Table1',function(err,data) {

        callback(data);
        mssql.close();

    });
});
```

[table2.js]

```
var mssql = require('mssql');
var config = {
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  server: 'server', 
  database: 'db',
  stream: true, 
  options: {
    encrypt: true 
  }
}

mssql.connect(config, function(err) {
    var request = new mssql.Request(); 
    request.query('select * from Table2',function(err,data) {

        callback(data);
        mssql.close();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you need things like config/ database connections, wrap the modules in

```
module.exports = function (db) {
// code for table1 or table 2
}
```

Now all you need is a central place, can be `app.js / server.js`, where you get the connection params from a config file and `require('./path/to/table')(db)`

`app.js`

```
const db = {
'mssql': {
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  server: 'server', 
  database: 'db',
  stream: true, 
  options: {
    encrypt: true 
  }
}
```

`table1.js`

```
module.exports = function(db) {
  const mssql = require('mssql');

  mssql.connect(db.mssql, function (err) {
    // do what ever
});
}
```

Comment: Shameless plug, take a look at https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap/blob/master/minions/index.js#L12 if you go a level deeper and have one place where you require all your tables/ modules and then inject that into the app